# The difference between thin width of tyre and thick tyre width

Tags: tire

According to physics doesn't it say that lesser the are greater to force or grip. So why wheelies performed on tyres with greater thickness?

Comment: Thin tires are generally seen on road bikes.  It's hard to perform a wheelie on a road bike, and the motivation to do so is generally absent, for the road bike rider.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Wheelies can be performed on any tyre.

Answer (score 3):

Tricks in general are often done on bikes with fairly wide tyres, so that might be why you're seeing wheelies on such bikes. They can be done in other bikes though. One of my riding buddies is prone to doing wheelies on his road bike, though he's old enough to know better.

In general, on a dry road, all bike tyres have plenty of grip, but bikes designed for wider tyres tend to be tougher and more suited to the landing (which would be rather harsh if your front tyre was 23mm and 7bar.

Comment: *he's old enough to know better.* whaaat old man can't have fun no more :P Also note you can gently place down the front wheel after a wheelie, so it's not always a harsh landing.

Comment: @stijn *Also note you can gently place down the front wheel after a wheelie* Speak for yourself, I always seem to manage to slam my wheel into the ground with the force of a sledge hammer!

Comment: @T_Bacon yeah it's not exactly the easiest thing to learn

Comment: @stijn only that it doesn't impress the people around, who may be a little closer for their own comfort.